# inavalid element type in machine learning model

Tags: javascript, react-native, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I'm using a simple model of `@tensorflow/tfjs`which simply shows accuracy. The same code when ran in code sandbox doesn't give any error while running it in visual studio code an invariant type error occur. My code is attached below. Also guide about input shape and unit term used in code and how to implement this code in react native.

```
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native'
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs";
import * as ft from '@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgpu';
//import { writeFileSync, readFileSync } from 'fs';

(async() => {
  await ft.ready 
 // then do all operations on the backend
})()


const model = tf.sequential({
  layers: [
    tf.layers.dense({ inputShape: [784], units: 32, activation: "relu" }),
    tf.layers.dense({ units: 10, activation: "softmax" })
  ]
});
model.weights.forEach(w => {
  console.log(w.name, w.shape);
});
model.weights.forEach(w => {
  const newVals = tf.randomNormal(w.shape);
  // w.val is an instance of tf.Variable
  w.val.assign(newVals);
});
model.compile({
  optimizer: "sgd",
  loss: "categoricalCrossentropy",
  metrics: ["accuracy"]
});
const data = tf.randomNormal([100, 784]);
const labels = tf.randomUniform([100, 10]);

function onBatchEnd(batch, logs) {
  console.log("Accuracy", logs.acc);
}

// Train for 5 epochs with batch size of 32.
model
  .fit(data, labels, {
    epochs: 5,
    batchSize: 32,
    callbacks: { onBatchEnd }
  })
  .then(info => {
    console.log("Final accuracy", info.history.acc);
  });
```

And the error

[image]

Comment: You also need to import the react native package. `import '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native';`

Comment: @edkeveked it is giving this error now like "the highest priority backend 'rn-webgl' has not yet been initialized. Make sure to await tf.ready() before calling other metgods"

Comment: Add  `await tf.ready()` before using any other methods. Because the backend is asynchronous

Comment: i added these lines now                                                                               import * as ft from '@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgpu';

const init = async () => {
    await ft.ready();

    // Now we can create tensors and run ops.
    
};

init();                                                                                                                 
the error says "getpropertyAsobject: property '_fb requireBatchedBridge' is not an object                                                                                                            no stack

Comment: You added the package `'@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native'` as suggested ?

Comment: yes...i did this too

Comment: You should create the model only after `tf.ready`. In your async function you can call a function let's say `init()` that will contain the code where you create the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the `@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native` package. Additionnaly, `tf.ready()` should be be used if the backend is asynchronous
Here is an example of how your react app should look like

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native';

export class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isTfReady: false,
    };
  }

  init() {
    const model = tf.sequential({
        layers: [
            tf.layers.dense({
                inputShape: [784],
                units: 32,
                activation: "relu"
            }),
            tf.layers.dense({
                units: 10,
                activation: "softmax"
            })
        ]
    });
    model.weights.forEach(w => {
        console.log(w.name, w.shape);
    });
    model.weights.forEach(w => {
        const newVals = tf.randomNormal(w.shape);
        // w.val is an instance of tf.Variable
        w.val.assign(newVals);
    });
    model.compile({
        optimizer: "sgd",
        loss: "categoricalCrossentropy",
        metrics: ["accuracy"]
    });
    const data = tf.randomNormal([100, 784]);
    const labels = tf.randomUniform([100, 10]);

    function onBatchEnd(batch, logs) {
        console.log("Accuracy", logs.acc);
    }

    // Train for 5 epochs with batch size of 32.
    model
        .fit(data, labels, {
            epochs: 5,
            batchSize: 32,
            callbacks: {
                onBatchEnd
            }
        })
        .then(info => {
            console.log("Final accuracy", info.history.acc);
        });
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    // Wait for tf to be ready.
    await tf.ready();
    // Signal to the app that tensorflow.js can now be used.
    this.setState({
      isTfReady: true,
    });
  }


  render() {
    init()
    //
  }
}
```